# Single Instance Storage layers

Tags: .net, storage, deduplication, sis

I have a data storage requirement which is an excellent candidate for single instance storage and deduplication.

Can anyone suggest any .Net compatible libraries or systems which handles SIS and deduplication, either with SQL Server as an actual back end or its own high performance storage engine?  What have peoples experiences been with such engines, and are there any pit falls to watch out for?

Regards

Moo

Comment: Can you describe your requirements more? Then I can better answer if there is something your your or if you even need an library. the most basic dedup types are pretty easy to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it something like [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/) that you are looking for?